# Rating System: Statistically significant with weighted entries

Tags: statistics, average

The title may be a bit confusing because I not exactly sure how to do/explain what I am after.

I have judges rating an object on a score 1-100, where the majority of objects will in the range 85-95 most of the time (90% or so).

3 judges are needed for the system to be "confident" of the 1-100 rating, however 3 judges judging can take a very long time.

To speed up the system, non-judges can also rate the object but their rating is weighted lower than a judge. Judges have a weight of 2500, and all non-members have their own weight based on a 0 to 2500 scale.

The approval/deny cut off is at a score of 90.

I am looking for a method to cut off ratings once a score of at least 90 has not only been reached but its unlikely that the # of judges it will take to reach 3 will not put it under 90. That is, if 1 judge has rated then a relatively low score from 2 judges will not put in under 90, vice versa if 2 judges have rated, a relatively low score from 1 judge will not put in under 90.

As an example, if 2 judges give the object a score of 97 and 1 member with weight 1600 gives it a score of 99, that is a total of 2*97*2500+99*1600, which would trigger the system that it is very unlikely that the 3rd judge will give it a score low enough to make the average dip below 90, therefore rating should end early, and without the 3rd needed judge.

Comment: Conceptually the approach suggested by Nameless of calibrating probabilities from data should work. There are some issues in practical implementation. One, selection bias. If judges and non-judges can choose whether and when to assign a rating, that timing carries information. For example, judges may rate quickly if they like an object but may take long if they are unsure. So a proper calibration should incorporate timings of ratings. The other issue is that implementing a scheme to cut off ratings based on early ratings may change the behavior of early judges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply apply Bayes' rule. Basically, what you want to do is predict how likely it is that the object will be accepted/denied, given enough time (so that 3 judges make their rating), based only on the first judge rating.

So suppose you have the rating of one judge with rating 95. Then you can calculate from all objects (where you already have 3 ratings) the conditional probability
$$Pr(AvRating_3<90|r_1=95)=\frac{Pr(r_1=95|AvRating_3<90) Pr(AvRating_3<90)}{Pr(r_1=95)},$$
where $AvRating_3(=1/3[r_1+r_2+r_3])$ is the rating you use when you have the ratings of all 3 judges, and $r_1$ is the first judge rating of the object.

This probability tells you how likely it is that the final rating after 3 judge-ratings will be below 90 (your cutoff), given that the first rating is, say, $r_1=95$. A new rule based on this probability can be something like: if the conditional probability that the final rating is below 90 is small enough (say, below 20%), then you already approve the object (even though you only have 1 rating so far, but you know, statistically, that with enough time it will likely be approved eventually).

But this only works if you already have many objects with 3 ratings, so that you can calculate these conditional probabilities for all values of $r_1$. For example, if there is no object yet where the first rating was $r_1=95$, then you cannot calculate the above probability. In that case, as an approximation you could average over the immediate neighbors, e.g.,
$$Pr(AvRating_3<90|r_1=95)=\frac{1/3[Pr(r_1=94|AvRating_3<90)+Pr(r_1=95|AvRating_3<90)+Pr(r_1=96|AvRating_3<90)] Pr(AvRating_3<90)}{1/3[Pr(r_1=94)+Pr(r_1=95)+Pr(r_1=96)]},$$
and if, say, there is no object with $r_1=95$ in your data, you instead use
$$Pr(AvRating_3<90|r_1=95)=\frac{1/2[Pr(r_1=94|AvRating_3<90)+Pr(r_1=96|AvRating_3<90)] Pr(AvRating_3<90)}{1/2[Pr(r_1=94)+Pr(r_1=96)]}.$$

Comment: This seems like a good method for figuring out the probability of a particular person (judge) and how likely it is be above or below cutoff. However, it does not consider non-judges with weights. Typically, 3-5 non-judges have rated before 1 judge has rated. Am I safe to assume if I apply a normalized weight to each probability and then average them (basically a weighted average probability) that this will consider all options and be mathematically ideal?

Comment: One issue I see with this method is that it may assume there are only 3 judges total, when in reality there are about 10. Only 3 of the 10 need to judge for it to be approved or not, so this means if r1 judged it would need the probability of the pairs r1 r2 r3, r1 r3 r4, r1 r2 r4, etc for every combination because we do not know who of the 10 besides r1 might judge next.

Comment: On the last comment: That's not an issue. Whether 3 or 10 judges rated doesn't matter. You just need to know whether an object was approved or denied. So in all the above equations you can replace $AvRating_3<90$ with "Object denied", and calculate the probabilities from this. So you also don't need the sequence of $r_1,r_2$ etc., just whether the object was approved. Again, what you want to do is predict the probability that the object will be denied/approved, based only on the first rating.

Comment: About non-judge ratings: you are right, there are probably better methods to incorporate this. Bayes' rule would still work, but then you have to calculate something like $Pr(Object denied|r_1=95,n_1=90,n_2=70)$, where $n_i$ are the non-judge ratings. You need even more data than before to do this.